# Compare different datsets columns - Python/SQL

Tags: python, sql, pandas

So i got two datasets, one with firstName, lastName, email & bankaccount columns and one with a description of bank details.
I want to see if a lastName/bankaccount is in the description to see if someone paid.

However the description is like very long so it first contains someones bankaccount than some text with their lastname.
The description looks something like: "NLXXRABOXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX firstName lastName date"

I currently have both datasets in pandas & sql, currently this is my best guess:

`q5 = """ SELECT user.email FROM user WHERE book.description LIKE %(SELECT * from user WHERE user.lastName)% ; """ engine.execute(q5).fetchall()`

Is something possible or with pandas?

Edit: the description column needs to be compared to the total lastName/bankAccount column of the other dataset, because it contains 750 rows. So it should be some kind of loop or a statement within these statements, but I did not find the solution yet

Comment: Question should include reproducible datasets and yourapproach to solve the problem in order to get better response.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas read_sql_query or use str.contains()

```
df['fisrtName'].str.contains('John', na=False)
df.read_sql_query( """sql statment""", con)
```

It allows you to use SQL syntax in pandas.

Another way maybe use filter...but it select columns wich contain the name.

```
df.filter(like='name')
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the thing is that the description column needs to be compared to the total lastName/bankAccount column of the other dataset, because it contains 750 rows. So it should be some kind of loop or a statement within these statements, but I did not find the solution yet